# remoteEntry.js was not being fetched despite being defined?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

Please find below the `webpack.config.js` for host/container

```js
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      remotes: {
        subA: "sub_a@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
        subB: "sub_b@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js",
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
```

As shown above, I've defined `subA` & `subB` to be remote dependencies and I would expect once host being loaded, `http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js` & `http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js` both being fetched but this is not the case

[image]

**Observation**

My guess is, the above could be due to at host level, I did not `import` source code from `subA` and hence Webpack is smart enough not to fetch `remoteEntry.js`, and if I `import` source code from `subA`, it works fine, I can see `http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js` being fetched.

However, I don't believe my guess was correct.

On host level, I've `import` source code from `subA`, and I did not `import` source code from `subB`, however `http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js` will be fetched as well [image]

The image above showing that both `remoteEntry.js` from `subA` and `subB` are being fetched by host, despite I did not `import` any source code from `subB`, the behaviour looks to me like Webpack either avoid the entire `remotes` plugin at host level, or if any of the remote dependencies being needed, `remoteEntry.js` will be fetched altogether?

I'm actually expecting host application will actually fetch all `remoteEntry.js` that are being defined at `remotes`, despite whether the source code is being used or not

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you say that it will load all js event if it doesn't use it. To improve on that you need lazy loading.

I had the same issue and i used different names for remoteEntry.js for example saremoteEntry.js,sbremoteEntry.js and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).